# Qt libraries on Mac

Tags: macos, qt

I'm developing a c++ program that uses the qt libraries, specifically the QtCore library. In the makefile I need to refer to the location of the directory that contains the libraries that I use. (I do not use QtCreator). I'm running on OSX 10.10.15.

I installed qt thru `brew install qt5`, all files are in /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.5.0/ but I cannot find neither libQtCore.a nor libQtCore.dyn

I also installed Qt thru the installer on the website http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux.html but still couldn't find the libraries.

Comment: Aren't you using `qmake`?

Comment: It worked for me on ubuntu when I installed thru `apt-get install qt-dev-all` (or some variant of it, I cant remember exactly)

Comment: You need to use `qmake`.  It knows where Qt has been installed.

Comment: How can I know where it is installed?

Comment: If memory serves, it should be in your path.  If not, in a terminal do find / -name "qmake".  In your project directory, do /path/to/qmake and then make.  My guess is that it is in /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.5.0/bin/qmake

Comment: well, my question is where are the libraries.. not the qmake. qmake is indeed already in my path

Comment: If you use `qmake`, it will generate a `Makefile` with the paths set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

On OS X Qt installed as set of frameworks [by default](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-deployment.html#building-qt-as-frameworks).

Comment: I'm new to Mac; Is there a quick way to work with qt libraries over OSX as if I was working over ubuntu (i.e. to link them in the usual way), or should I study OSX environment (framework, bundles etc.) before I touch it?

Comment: Please check this link http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-deployment.html#the-mac-deployment-tool

Comment: You can run macdeployqt against your bundle with executable. macdeployqt will copy Qt frameworks into the bundle and change references in the framework binaries to be loadable from your executable run.

Comment: @MaxGo the current information about deployment of Qt6 is on https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/macos-deployment.html